How to create a bi-directional bar chart?
I have a Python code which aims to plot multiple betting scenarios.
My code below returns this graph.
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

bet_details = {
    "Team 1": {"bet_amount": 1000, "price_per_share": 0.37, "bet_position": "L"}, 
    "Team 2": {"bet_amount": 1000, "price_per_share": 0.59, "bet_position": "W"}} # "L" for Lose, "W"  for Win

# Calculate P/L based on prediction market share model
def calculate_profit(bet_amount, odds, position, outcome):
    # Calculate the number of shares based on price per share
    shares = bet_amount / odds
    if position == outcome:
        return shares  # If bet is correct, return $1 per share
    else:
        return -bet_amount  # If bet is incorrect, lose the bet amount

# Function to simulate all scenarios and calculate P/L for each one
def simulate_bets(bet_details):
    # Generate all possible win/loss combinations for the given states
    scenarios = list(itertools.product(["W", "L"], repeat=len(bet_details)))
    
    # Initialize lists to store results
    scenario_results = []
    breakdown = []

    # Calculate P/L for each scenario
    for scenario in scenarios:
        scenario_name = " & ".join([f"{state}: {'Win' if outcome == 'W' else 'Lose'}" for state, outcome in zip(bet_details.keys(), scenario)])
        total_profit_loss = 0
        
        # Breakdown details for each state in this scenario
        state_breakdown = []

        # Calculate P/L for each state in the scenario
        for state, outcome in zip(bet_details.keys(), scenario):
            details = bet_details[state]
            bet_amount = details["bet_amount"]
            odds = details["odds"]
            position = details["bet_position"]
            
            # Calculate the profit/loss for this state in the current scenario
            profit_loss = calculate_profit(bet_amount, odds, position, outcome)
            total_profit_loss += profit_loss

            # Append breakdown information
            state_breakdown.append({
                "State": state,
                "Bet Amount": bet_amount,
                "Bet Position": position,
                "Bet Outcome": outcome,
                "P/L": profit_loss
            })

        # Add scenario results to main results
        scenario_results.append({"Scenario": scenario_name, "Total Profit/Loss": total_profit_loss})
        breakdown.extend(state_breakdown)

    # Create DataFrames for scenario overview and detailed breakdown
    df_scenarios = pd.DataFrame(scenario_results).sort_values(by="Total Profit/Loss", ascending=False)
    df_breakdown = pd.DataFrame(breakdown)
    
    # Plotting the scenario results
    plot_scenarios(df_scenarios)

    return df_scenarios, df_breakdown

def plot_scenarios(df_scenarios):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
    bars = ax.barh(df_scenarios['Scenario'], df_scenarios['Total Profit/Loss'], color=["green" if x > 0 else "red" for x in df_scenarios['Total Profit/Loss']])
    
    # Add labels
    ax.set_xlabel("Total Profit/Loss ($)")
    ax.set_title("Profit/Loss by Scenario")
    
    # Adding text labels for P/L values with alignment adjustment
    for bar in bars:
        width = bar.get_width()
        ax.text(width + (10 if width < 0 else -40), bar.get_y() + bar.get_height() / 2, f"{width:.2f}",
                va="center", ha="left" if width < 0 else "right", color="black", fontweight="bold")
    
    plt.show()

Is there a way to create a graph that shows the breakdown of each bet P/L on a bar opposite of each other and shows the bet name and P/L. When trying, the best I could achieve was this messy outcome (graph).
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

# Define the bet details for each team in a dictionary
bet_details = {
    "Team 1": {"bet_amount": 100, "odds": 0.37, "bet_position": "L"},  # "L" for Lose, "W" for Win
    "Team 2": {"bet_amount": 100, "odds": 0.59, "bet_position": "W"},
}

# Calculate P/L based on prediction market share model
def calculate_profit(bet_amount, odds, position, outcome):
    # Calculate the number of shares based on price per share
    shares = bet_amount / odds
    if position == outcome:
        return shares  # If bet is correct, return $1 per share
    else:
        return -bet_amount  # If bet is incorrect, lose the bet amount

# Function to simulate all scenarios and calculate P/L for each one
def simulate_bets(bet_details):
    # Generate all possible win/loss combinations for the given teams
    scenarios = list(itertools.product(["W", "L"], repeat=len(bet_details)))
    
    # Initialize lists to store results
    scenario_results = []
    breakdown = []

    # Calculate P/L for each scenario
    for scenario in scenarios:
        scenario_name = " & ".join([f"{team}: {'Win' if outcome == 'W' else 'Lose'}" for team, outcome in zip(bet_details.keys(), scenario)])
        total_profit_loss = 0
        
        # Breakdown details for each team in this scenario
        team_breakdown = []

        # Calculate P/L for each team in the scenario
        for team, outcome in zip(bet_details.keys(), scenario):
            details = bet_details[team]
            bet_amount = details["bet_amount"]
            odds = details["odds"]
            position = details["bet_position"]
            
            # Calculate the profit/loss for this team in the current scenario
            profit_loss = calculate_profit(bet_amount, odds, position, outcome)
            total_profit_loss += profit_loss

            # Append breakdown information
            team_breakdown.append({
                "Team": team,
                "Bet Amount": bet_amount,
                "Bet Position": position,
                "Bet Outcome": outcome,
                "P/L": profit_loss
            })

        # Add scenario results to main results
        scenario_results.append({"Scenario": scenario_name, "Total Profit/Loss": total_profit_loss})
        breakdown.extend(team_breakdown)

    # Create DataFrames for scenario overview and detailed breakdown
    df_scenarios = pd.DataFrame(scenario_results).sort_values(by="Total Profit/Loss", ascending=False)
    df_breakdown = pd.DataFrame(breakdown)
    
    # Plotting the scenario results
    plot_scenarios(df_scenarios, df_breakdown)

    return df_scenarios, df_breakdown

def plot_scenarios(df_scenarios, df_breakdown):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
    
    # Main scenario profit/loss bars
    bars = ax.barh(df_scenarios['Scenario'], df_scenarios['Total Profit/Loss'], 
                   color=["green" if x > 0 else "red" for x in df_scenarios['Total Profit/Loss']],
                   edgecolor='black')
    
    # Adding text labels for scenario P/L values
    for bar in bars:
        width = bar.get_width()
        ax.text(width + (10 if width < 0 else -40), bar.get_y() + bar.get_height() / 2, f"{width:.2f}",
                va="center", ha="left" if width < 0 else "right", color="black", fontweight="bold")
    
    # Create a mirrored bar for team-level P/L breakdown
    for index, scenario in enumerate(df_scenarios['Scenario']):
        # Get team breakdown for this scenario
        team_data = df_breakdown[df_breakdown['Team'].isin(bet_details.keys())]
        
        # Calculate the profit/loss for each team in this scenario
        for team in bet_details.keys():
            details = bet_details[team]
            profit_loss = calculate_profit(details['bet_amount'], details['odds'], details['bet_position'], 
                                            "W" if df_scenarios.iloc[index]['Total Profit/Loss'] > 0 else "L")
            # Create a bar for the team's P/L on the opposite side
            ax.barh(scenario, profit_loss, left=-profit_loss, color='lightblue', edgecolor='black', height=0.4)
            
            # Add team P/L labels on the opposite side
            ax.text(-profit_loss - 5, index, f"{team}: {profit_loss:.2f}", va='center', color='black', fontweight='bold')

    # Set labels and title
    ax.set_xlabel("Total Profit/Loss ($)")
    ax.set_title("Profit/Loss by Scenario with Team Breakdown")

    plt.show()

# Example usage:
df_results, df_breakdown = simulate_bets(bet_details)
print(df_results)  # Scenario summary with total P/L
print(df_breakdown)  # Detailed P/L breakdown by team


Your question currently contains a lot of code calculating the data to be plotted, which is irrelevant to your core question. Please reduce the code to an MRE. One way to do this is simply provide a hard-coded data structure containing the final data at the beginning of your code and then only include plotting code, or you can use toy example data. Then you might also be able to better explain what kind of output you want (a sketch would go a long way here).
